# Issue with deploying GWT to Cloudfoundry

Tags: eclipse, gwt, cloud-foundry

I am trying to get a a basic GWT App working in cloudfoundry.

The issue is From Eclipse,its all good.and it says deployed and started.

When I got to URL,error is: VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND.

Also,From Eclipse,Its Ok except usage screen looks suspicious.
Screenshot:[image]

Comment: Hi Barney. I'm working on reproducing this with a simple example. If you would rather open a ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com, and submit your code, we can work with that and post the results of our investigation here.

Comment: Barney - could you please explain in more detail, the process you used to deploy from STS? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Barney, since I didn't have much to work with here, I picked a simple first GWT sample> http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWT/article.html . After deploying this successfully locally, I moved on to attempting a cloudfoundry deployment. One way to deploy easily to cloudfoundry is with a WAR, so I used this to obtain one for deployment > http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/ . At least the deployment using this approach worked, as can be seen here > http://gwtsimple.cloudfoundry.com/ . Please take a look, and share your thoughts.

Comment: @eightyoctane strange,didnt get notifications..the issue is resolved.I used right click and deploy module from eclipse for war and deployed tomcat7 directly.thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used right click on module descriptor *.gwt.xml and deploy for creating war.
and deployed on tomcat 7 as described here:
[tomcat 7 on cloudfoundry](http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/18/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework/)
and it worked nice.
you can use above steps for deploying gwt on cloudfoundry.com